# What does background-color: transparent mean?

Tags: html, css

I've read some code and I saw this `background-color: transparent`.

I don't know what it is, so I searched the internet, but I couldn't find a resource to explain what it means.

What does `background-color: transparent` mean and/or do?

Comment: [By default, the background color is transparent, basically meaning that there is no background color.](https://cssreference.io/property/background-color/)

Comment: Do you mean you're having trouble understanding what "background color" and/or "transparent" mean? Because if you know what both of those things mean, then this seems fairly self-explanatory. But if you don't, then understandably very few sources seem to explain it (except the one Robert has cited).

Answer (score 7):

As the name suggests, `background-color: transparent` means you can see through the background of the element, i.e. its background color would *appear* to be identical to the background color seen on its parent element.

Note that this is different from `background-color: white`, because if the parent element has a background color other than white, given element will have a different color, i.e. white.

Also keep in mind that it is the *initial* value of [`background-color` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color). Meaning, if you do not explicitly specify the background-color, it will take the value `transparent`.

Here's an example to give you an idea:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container > div {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: aqua;
}

.bg-transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: white;
}

.bg-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container bg-blue">
  <div class="bg-white">White</div>
  <div class="bg-transparent">Transparent</div>
</div>

<div class="container bg-white">
  <div class="bg-white">White</div>
  <div class="bg-transparent">Transparent</div>
</div>

<div class="container bg-yellow">
  <div class="bg-white">White</div>
  <div class="bg-transparent">Transparent</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Transparent doesn't mean the same background color as its parent. An element with a transparent background color doesn't have a background color - you can see its parent's background *through* it, but it doesn't gain or inherit the color for itself. It's like glass; if you hold a piece of glass in front of a red wall, the glass doesn't turn red; you just see the red wall through the glass.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, I found it a bit difficult to put it into words. I tried to find the wording in the spec, but couldn't find anything, probably because most English speakers understand what "transparent" is. I have tried to modify the wording, but feel free to update it.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. It's not clear from the question how MDN and W3Schools (which I'd have no problem citing here) are inadequate, so I've been trying to figure out what exactly is being asked. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `background-color:transparent` it means, that you don't want to have a `background-color` for this element. A typical usecase would be: if you are overlapping another element and want to see the underlying element with it's content or color.

Answer (score 0):

Background is used to make the color transparent. Also remember that you can use it in "color", "border" etc.

```
color:transparent;
border-color:transparent;
background-color:transparent;
```